# d3.map() issue with retrieving data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

ANSWER - nameById.get(id)

(from Lars Kotthoff in comments)

---

Attempting to load .tsv to return state names but can't access values. I've stripped out everything else to show what I'm missing. On click I can see the data in nameById but attempts to reference data have failed. I've attempted appending strings on the way in as in "id_"+d.id etc ... but no luck. Thanks for any ideas.

console output on click - curious what the 'o' before the first '{' is as well (object?)

```
undefined
undefined
o {1: "Alabama", 2: "Alaska", 4: "Arizona", 5: "Arkansas", 6: "California"…}
```

salient html:

```
<button id="but">click</button>

<script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.select('#but').on('click', function() {
    console.log(nameById[1]);
    console.log(nameById["1"]);
    console.log(nameById);
});

var nameById = d3.map();
queue()
    .defer(d3.tsv, "tsv/us-state-names.tsv", function(d) { nameById.set(d.id, d.name); })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
}
</script>
```

and the .tsv - copied, as usual, from an excellent d3 example:

```
id  code    name
1   AL  Alabama
2   AK  Alaska
4   AZ  Arizona
5   AR  Arkansas
6   CA  California
8   CO  Colorado
9   CT  Connecticut
10  DE  Delaware
11  DC  District of Columbia
12  FL  Florida
13  GA  Georgia
15  HI  Hawaii
16  ID  Idaho
17  IL  Illinois
18  IN  Indiana
19  IA  Iowa
20  KS  Kansas
21  KY  Kentucky
22  LA  Louisiana
23  ME  Maine
24  MD  Maryland
25  MA  Massachusetts
26  MI  Michigan
27  MN  Minnesota
28  MS  Mississippi
29  MO  Missouri
30  MT  Montana
31  NE  Nebraska
32  NV  Nevada
33  NH  New Hampshire
34  NJ  New Jersey
35  NM  New Mexico
36  NY  New York
37  NC  North Carolina
38  ND  North Dakota
39  OH  Ohio
40  OK  Oklahoma
41  OR  Oregon
42  PA  Pennsylvania
44  RI  Rhode Island
45  SC  South Carolina
46  SD  South Dakota
47  TN  Tennessee
48  TX  Texas
49  UT  Utah
50  VT  Vermont
51  VA  Virginia
53  WA  Washington
54  WV  West Virginia
55  WI  Wisconsin
56  WY  Wyoming
60  AS  America Samoa
64  FM  Federated States of Micronesia
66  GU  Guam
68  MH  Marshall Islands
69  MP  Northern Mariana Islands
70  PW  Palau
72  PR  Puerto Rico
74  UM  U.S. Minor Outlying Islands
78  VI  Virgin Islands of the United States
```

Comment: Solved it using a standalone nameobj = {} and nameobj[d.id] = d.name in the return function. Posting if anyone's looking. Still wondering what was wrong.

Comment: You need to use `nameById.get(id)`.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 maps aren't objects and don't behave in the same way. You need to use `.get()` in this case:

```
nameById.get(id)
```